# Каково значение и происхождение слова "куцый"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Вроде как покоцать - это порезать, покусать.

А откуда корни происходят?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этимология слова "куцый" по двум словарям:

1) Большой этимологический словарь русского языка (сост. Климова М.В, 2013 год):

КУЦЫЙ - от восточнославянского кус (кусок), нечто откушенное, возникновение XVI век.

2) Историко-этимологический словарь П.Я. Черных (1994 год): В русском языке слово довольно позднее: у Пушкина в "Барышне-крестьянке" -  куцая кобылка. В словарях - с 1847 года. Очевидно, вместо кусый. Замена С на Ц табуистического порядка, слово "куцый" с некоторого времени получило название "чёрт", стало одним из его эпитетов. Сравнить: куций (укр.) - чёрт.

Осталось выяснить происхождение "кусать", но  его в первых двух словарях нет, зато оно есть у Шанского:

КУСАТЬ Общеслав. Суф. производное (с интенсивом -s-) (ср. кромсать) от той же основы, что и лит. kándu «кусаю». Исходное *kondsati (ds > s, on > ǫ > у, конечное безударное и отпало). Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Comment: Покоцать не имеет отношения к покусать. Порезать, порубить, покромсать. Так что не стоит двигаться в направлении "покусать" и украинских чертей. Ваше "очевидно" - не вполне очевидно.

Comment: ОП спрашивает сразу про два слова: куцый и (по)коцать. Ему представляется что эти слова однокоренные. (я согласен). Кусать, кушать - действия производимые ртом. Мне кажется что это от другого корня. (Целовать: kiss, kuss - нем. ) Куцый - это то что покоцали.

Answer (score -1):

Кец на иврите – это конец, прекращение. На лицо древний корень, который пророс даже в современные языки. На английском похожее cut.

Answer (score -2):

Куцый (невзрачный) от Кутний (кутий - диалект.) < Кут (угол - ограниченное пространство/объём) > Кутя (детёныш - "маленький"). Т. е. Кут - это основной источник, но и другие близкие формы играли роль ...

См http://www.proza.ru/2016/04/25/937 :  Как разошлись Кот, Кит морской и Каюта.

Comment: На нашем ресурсе не допускается распространение лженаучной (так называемой любительской) этимологии. С отличительными признаками этих теорий Вы можете познакомится в лекциях А.Зализняка или, коротко, [здесь](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/%d0%9b%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5).

Comment: Я знаком ...  Обоснуйте покороче лже научность моих тезисов. Или вы не знаете переходов Т в Ц ?

Comment: Тем более, что нет бесспорной этимологии Куцый. Где вас учат - таких модераторов ?

Comment: Я не модератор — обычный участник. А.Зализняк объяснял, что один из первых признаков "любительской этимологии" — утверждение о том, что гласные в этимологии не имеют существенного значения, значение имеет только "костяк согласных". Как только я нашёл это по Вашей ссылке, так сразу и стало понятно. Прочитайте внимательно материал по моей ссылке — Вам это будет полезно.

Comment: Отсутствие общепризнанной этимологии не является оправданием распространения "любительских" теорий.

Comment: Немножко подумайте логически и убедитесь - моя версия не более любительская чем известные ("научные").  Логические цепочки (здравые рассуждения) строить умеете ? В моих высказываниях нет ни одного признака "Народной этимологии" от Зализняка.

Comment: Ссылка - это для любителей...                                                           
Конкретно в этих моих постах про Куцый - что вам показалось любительским ?

Comment: Ладно - не будем спорить. Я всего лишь высказал свою вполне логически обоснованную версию.  А вы, пожалуйста, проявите себя как здравомыслящий специалист здесь - , https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444150/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%A1%D0%A0%D0%AF-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%97%D0%92%D0%A3%D0%9A-%D0%90