# Исконно русские слова на звук [а]

Tags: этимология, фонетика

Есть ли в литературном СРЯ исконные слова на **ЗВУК** [а]?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно! Ах, а (союз), ась, али, ай, абы... Слова типа *авось, авоська* технически начинаются со звука [ʌ], который может быть аллофоном (вариантом) фонем /а/ и /о/. В этих словах приходится говорить о гиперфонеме /о-а/, но этимологически там именно /а/. Более того, принято считать, что слова, образованные в русском языке, даже с помощью иностранных аффиксов, также исконные, например: альдоновый (русский суффикс), аннигилированный (русский суффикс). Но последнее обстоятельство ломает устойчивое представление об отсутствии исконно русских слов на А.

Впрочем, слов типа *али* мало, поэтому, говоря об отсутствии исконных слов на А, люди не допускают ошибку (из истории языка известно, что исконные слова на А получали протетический (начальный) йот, ср. аз и яз [jас] «я»), но поступают не вполне аккуратно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86438/discussion-on-answer-by-aer------).

Answer (score 2):

Я не дочитал, простите, вашего ответа - не дал Бог сил всё это переварить.

Отвечаю на вопрос по сути.
Вопрос поставлен не совсем корректно. Какие слова считать исконно-русскими?
Прямых индоевропейских, не подвергшихся изменениям корней, если мне память не изменяет, в русском что-то около 0,03%, праславянских - 0,2%. Древнерусских 3-4%. Остальные либо заимствованы, либо утратили связь с исходными, то есть стали как бы другими словами. *Аналогичная картина вообще в любом языке, меняются только цифры. Исконных слов очень мало.*

Поэтому при постановке подобных вопросов требуется точно сказать, по отношению к какому периоду относится утверждение "исконно русские". Тем не менее более или менее обоснованный ответ даже на нечетко сформулированный ответ существует.
Все знаменательные, начинавшиеся с А слова, существовавшие на момент разделения восточнославянской языковой общности (условно - VIII-XI века) под действием исторических фонетических законов приобрели Йот в качестве (начальной) протезы, то есть стали начинаться на Я. Этот процесс не затронул междометия и союзы (включая просторечные) и более поздние заимствования. 
а так же старославянизмы, возникшие относительно недавно просторечия и имена собственные.

Comment: Исконно русские слова — слова, существующие издавна, постоянно, искони. Под исконно русской лексикой понимаются те слова, которые образовались непосредственно в русском языке в разные периоды его становления: индоевропейский язык (конец эпохи неолита) → общеславянский язык (приблизительно до VII  века нашей эры) → восточнославянский язык (приблизительно до XIV  века нашей эры) → русский язык. (https://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/6-klass/leksika-frazeologiia-leksikografiia-15751/iskonno-russkie-i-zaimstvovannye-slova-10520/re-a518df81-a401-4de0-bb9b-9522811fe4fa)

Comment: @М_Г  помилуйте, это ж тарабарщина какая-то от ретивого автора. Откройте Фасмера - и убедитесь, что ни одно знаменательное слово в русском языке не "образовывалось" на пустом месте. Всегда есть какой-то генезис, выносящий слово за пределы конретного языка. Ну а про существование "русского языка" в праиндоевропейский период - это вообще хоть на стенку вешай... Фоменки отдыхают.

Comment: Но и даже если все эти несуразицы вынести за скобки, непонятно, зачем такая каша, кому понадобилось относить в одну категорию древнейшие слова, общие для идоевропейских и, скажем, современные жаргонизмы и неологизмы?! "Гуглить" - это исконно русское слово?По какому это принципу и чего ради?!

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, вопрос насчет "исконно русских на букву А" слов впервые поставил на популярном уровне Лев Успенский, в "Слове о словах". Конечно же, он  в мыслях не мог держать, что придется считать современные слова и древнейшие паниндоевропеизмы одного поля ягодой.

Comment: Что значит "слово образовалось" неясно, а как правильно сказать? Возникло? Первородилось?

Comment: Там не про существование "русского языка" в праиндоевропейский период, а о том, что есть слова унаследованные, а не привнесенные, их можно считать исконными.

Comment: Да никак. Дело не в термине, а в принципиально неправильном подходе. Я не принимаю не слово "образовалось", а то, то оно-де образовалось в русском языке - и поэтому оно русское. Строго говоря, все слова или заимствуются или  конструируются из ранее заимствованных. Ну вот классический пример - слово промышленность от слова "промысел", его чуть ли не Достоевский придумал. Но можно ли считать его образовавшимся внутри русского языка?!

Comment: *Там не про существование "русского языка" в праиндоевропейский период,* - да?! А это как понимать? *которые образовались непосредственно в русском языке в разные периоды его становления*?! То есть ***исконно***(!) русского слово образовалось в период, когда русского языка в помине не было?!

Comment: @М_Г посмотрите сначала здесь, а то движок уже ругается. http://lib.ru/PROZA/USPENSKIJ_L/slovo.txt_with-big-pictures.html#27 Здесь вся "проблема" как она есть, без наворотов про ПИЕ язык....

Comment: "В разные периоды его становления" — неверно, они хотели сказать "в его предшественниках", но для школьников и так сойдет, так даже "патриотичней".